# How to add a date to a cell next to an cell with an imported value

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-charts, google-sheets-timestamp

In column A I have a value added each day from the tab/cell TOTAL/A1 by this script:

```
function dailyLog() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName('TOTAL');
  var logSheet = ss.getSheetByName('TOTAL DIAGRAM');
  var lastRow = logSheet.getLastRow();
  // logSheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 1).setValue(new Date());  // insert timestamp on the row below
  var range = sourceSheet.getDataRange();
  range.copyTo(logSheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 1), {contentsOnly: true});
}
```

What I want is to have the date when it was added and I try to achieve that with the script:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if (e.range.getSheet().getSheetName() == 'TOTAL CHAR' && e.range.getColumn() == 1) {
    e.range.offset(0,1).setValue(e.value.length>0 ? new Date() : '');
  }
}
```

But it is only adding a date when I manually put a value in a cell. If the script is adding a value there is no date added.

Can this be done in any other way, or can Script 1 add the date to a cell to the right if the added value, as it is today it is added below?

Answer (score 0):

On edit triggers are triggered only by manual changes.

If you already are using a script to paste data by using the copyTo method, use that script to add the date of when the data was copied.

Among many ways to do this, maybe you could found the [offset method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#offsetrowoffset-columnoffset) handy.